# C function header generator

Tags: c

I know it's not a big deal to write a function header, but I will admit I am being lazy here.

Is there any tool to generate function headers? I think it's easy to add or delete a field within the function header if it's maintained using a tool.

Example:

```
/**************************************************************************** 
* NAME:        name                                     
* DESCRIPTION: text 
* ARGUMENTS:   args 
* RETURNS:     void
***************************************************************************/
```

If tomorrow, I plan to add two new fields, "date", and "reentrant", the tool should be able to do this:

```
/**************************************************************************** 
* NAME:        name                                    (date) 
* DESCRIPTION: text 
* ARGUMENTS:   args 
* RETURNS:     void
* RE-ENTRANT :
***************************************************************************/
```

The closest that I could find is following
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=938. However it's VI editor dependent, and I am not VI's greatest fan.

Some simple script should also do.

Comment: Add or delete a field to what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570917/extracting-c-c-function-prototypes

Comment: doxygen does some version of this...

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on doxygen

Comment: What is the environment you are developing in? Visual Studio, some other IDE or no IDE? Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: Thanks for linking to that Vim script... it looks pretty neat.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest splitting what you are trying to do into two separate parts.

A comment block with lines re-stating the arguments to a function is of no use.  Everyone who reads the code can see what the arguments are.  Unless you're going to describe what the argument is used for, don't waste a line of code.

On the other hand, it is useful to pull out functions and their variables into documentation.  As mentioned in a comment by bcr, doxygen does a good job of this.  It's a similar tool to javadoc, but targeted at C / C++ and I've used it pretty extensively.

You can run the tool on a directory full of code, and it will automatically pull out the functions along with their parameters into documentation.  You don't need to have a comment block to get basic documentation of the names of functions and variables.  But if you've written a block with a description of the function, it will include that in the documents for you.

Read more here:
http://www.doxygen.nl/

Answer (score 0):

What is your ide?

- On some tools like Visual Studio, eclipse or other big IDE's it's built in or plug-ins (eclipse).
- On some editors like emacs, in the time that i was coding with it i wrote a small script that made that job. You can easily handle it with some `cat`, `grep` and `sed` calls. Or make some lisp code to do the job.

Comment: I dont use ant ide as of now, windows platform + SourceInsight use makefiles to build in CYGWIN platform.

Comment: I don't know sourceInsight, and i'm not used to windows environement. But on any platform you could write a script to do it easily: perl, lua or anything else? I hope someone will be able to answer your question better than me;