# Function prototype filters

Tags: c, function

Is there any kind of tool that only shows the function prototypes of a given source file?
I know Doxygen is doing such a thing, but what I find is a simple Linux command such as

```
$ filter-function-prototypes main.c
1: print_hello()
2: main()
```

where main.c is given as

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_hello() {
    printf("hello, world\n");
}

int main()
{
    print_hello();
}
```

Comment: Could probably be done with `grep` or similar tools.

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570917/extracting-c-c-function-prototypes

Comment: easy to write a shell script for this

Comment: [`cproto`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cproto/)?  It is not easy to write a shell script to do this properly (though you can get to perhaps 80% functionality with a shell script).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `ctags` can do that!

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=f main.c
```

There's some extra stuff in output but it can be handled with `sed` or `awk`.
Or `cut`

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=f cards.c | cut -c 51-
```

Answer (score 1):

Many C files are formatted like yours, with top-level definitions starting in column 1, and with at least an open parenthesis on the function declaration line.

So you could use this:

```
egrep -i '^[a-z].*\(' main.c
```

as your filter.