# How can I use a library's header files to generate a libfoo.sym file for use with libtool -export-symbols?

Tags: c++, c, linux, shared-libraries, libtool

I am building a shared library for the Debian GNU/Linux distribution and I am worried about the number of symbols from internal functions that it exports without any need. Since the library is built using autoconf/automake/libtool, the answer is easy: I can just add `-export-symbols libfoo.sym` to `libfoo_la_LDFLAGS` and specify only the symbols I want exported in that file.

But since this involves error-prone manual work, I figured that there has to be a better way. Is it possible to automate reading the (in this case) dozens of `.h` files that accompany the library and generate a first version of the `libfoo.syms` file.

Could I just use the C (or C++) compiler to do the busy work for me?

Comment: If you've used some sort of 'namespace' for the library API, you might consider using the `-export-symbols-regex REGEX` option.

Comment: @BrettHale yeah, I had considered that, but to be sure, I still need to read all those header files. (I am not the author.)

Comment: The only other way to automate the process that I can think of is to use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Chances are it is already installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to extracting function prototypes and covered here:
[Extracting C / C++ function prototypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570917/extracting-c-c-function-prototypes)

Answer (score 0):

> But since this involves error-prone manual work, I figured that there has to be a better way. Is it possible to automate reading the (in this case) dozens of .h files that accompany the library and generate a first version of the libfoo.syms file.

It might be more useful to use `nm` on the object files instead of trying to parse header files. `nm` can be told to restrict the output to just exports.

> Could I just use the C (or C++) compiler to do the busy work for me?

Certain compilers have tools to assist with this, like gcc's [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) support.

But the real problem is you must know what functions must be exported and which must not.