# GNU linker wildcard for -wrap option

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, gnu, ld

Is there a way of using the `-wrap` option for all functions defined in a source file, without listing them by hand?

I thought about some wildcard for that option, but my research resulted in nothing. I also considered investigating a way for extraction of source file functions with *make*, also without success.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `ctags` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570917/extracting-c-c-function-prototypes), `sed` to add `-wrap` in front of each and inject the result on the command line.

--- Edit ---

For example, something like:

```
a=`ctags -o- --fields=-fkst --c-kinds=f myprint.c | cut -f1 | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)/-wrap \1/g'`
echo $a
```

would give you:

```
-wrap main -wrap myprint
```

You can also combine everything in one line:

```
ld ... `ctags -o- --fields=-fkst --c-kinds=f myprint.c | cut -f1 | sed -e 's/^/-wrap /'`
```

Comment: Okay, with this command: `ctags -o- --fields=-fkst --c-kinds=f ../file.c`I managed to print to standard output a list of lines, each containing the following, `tab`-separated values: tag name, path and EX command. This is said to be the standard _ctags_ format. However I need a list of sole tag names, comma-separated. I couldn't find anything in the docs, nor other sources. Is there a way to achieve this through _ctags_ options or I have to use external tools? (btw we're working on windows, so `sed` is not an option).

Comment: use `cut` (to extract the first field, `sed` to add commas, `xargs` to obtain a list, etc. Any other tool like `awk` could be your friend to parse a list and transform it.

Comment: I had to add just:  | tr '\n' ' '  at the end to make it display in one line and works like a charm :) Now my final _makefile_ instruction looks like this: `CTAGS_WRAP = ./ctags.exe -o- --fields=-fkst --c-kinds=f myFile.c | cut -f1 | sed -e 's/^/-wrap /' | tr '\n' ' '` which prints `-wall f1 -wall f2 -wall f3 ...`

Comment: Sorry, to be precise it's `CTAGS_WRAP = ./ctags.exe -o- --fields=-fkst --c-kinds=f myFile.c | cut -f1 | sed -e 's/^/-Wl,-wrap,/' | tr '\n' ' ' ` to get the output in form: `-Wl,-wrap,f1 -Wl,-wrap,f2 -Wl,-wrap,f3 ...` for use with `ld`. (I couldn't edit the previous comment).