# Issue with ctags and indent (extract function definitions/declarations from source)

Tags: c, indentation, ctags

I can't really find something on google regarding this issue.

I want to parse (get all) function definitions and declarations from .c/.h files.

I know about ctags, cscope and clang (AST).

Since I liked the simplicity of ctags I decided to stick with that.

One problem that I encountered is that ctags doesn't output the whole parameter list if there is a line break in between them like so:

```
int my_function(
    int a, int b
);
```

Gives the output:

```
 $ ctags -x --c-kinds=fp so.c
 my_function      prototype     1 so.c             int my_function(
```

This can be remedied with a tool like [`indent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/indent):

```
 $ indent -kr so.c -o so-fixed.c
 $ ctags -x --c-kinds=fp so-fixed.c

 my_function      prototype     1 so-fixed.c       int my_function(int a, int b);
```

Ok, that works perfectly. Until you have to deal with variadic functions like:

```
int my_function(
    int a, int b, ...
);
```

Then the output of [`indent`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/indent) is no more usable to me:

```
int my_function(int a, int b, ...
    );
```

The bigger goal here is to cross-check parameter names defined in header files with the ones used in the actual implementation.

So that something like :

header.h

```
void my_function(int param);
```

impl.c

```
void my_function(int something_else) {
}
```

Would be caught.

Ultimately I know I could use clang with its AST output.

However, due to the complexity of the AST, this is something I want to avoid, if possible.

Comment: I see two options to resolve this issue at the moment: stupidly replace all `...` with a placeholder like `int variadic_fn_param` OR use `ctags` to get the function names and use the AST of clang to get the details (like parameter names etc.)

Comment: The purpose of ctags is to give the *position* of a symbol, thus it only contains the content of the line (since line numbers might change). But last I checked, ctags was unmaintained.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570917/extracting-c-c-function-prototypes ? `is no more usable to me:` So just remove the newline after `...`, seems trivial to `sed -z 's/\.\.\.[[:space:]]*);/...);/'`. `ross-check parameter names defined in header files with the ones used in the actual implementation.` Use https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-inconsistent-declaration-parameter-name.html

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for the link! I had a look at `clang-tidy` before and I was unable to find such a check. I think this solves my problem

Comment: @KamilCuk Ok looks like I got it working like I wanted. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll accept it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bigger goal here is to cross-check parameter names defined in header files with the ones used in the actual implementation.

For that, you can use clang-tidy with https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-inconsistent-declaration-parameter-name.html

Answer (score 1):

[Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io) provides a feature customizing the xref output.

```
$ cat /tmp/bar.c
int f(char /* int */ a,
      // int b, ...
          int
          *c,
          ...
      )
  ;
$ ~/bin/ctags -x --_xformat="%-16N %-10K %4n %-16F %{typeref} %{name}%{signature}" --kinds-C=+p -o - /tmp/bar.c |sed -e 's/typename://'
f                prototype     1 /tmp/bar.c       int f(char a,int * c,...)
```

See also https://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/output-xref.html?highlight=_xformat#xformat

For formatting the return type as you need, you may want to use sed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a look into it.